# Same image displayed in footer and body of PDF,but with different size in footer and body

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, pdf, printpdf

Same image want to display with different size in PDF. image size 20px in footer and 200px in page . In normal visualforce page it works fine but when rendered as PDF. it's not working, its overriding the footers height and width attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

When you render VF page as PDF, layout gets changed by Salesforce internally- you need to update css accordingly. Here you go: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004706&type=1